# Python using dict .get() method where value = 0

Tags: python, dictionary

(Python 2.7.2)
I would like to better understand why the default value is returned when using a dictionaries .get() method to find a key when the value mapped to the key is 0.

Consider the following

```
x = {1:0}

print x.get('1', 'a')

'a'
```

The same happens for an empty string, set, etc.

but if I do:

```
print x[1]
0
```

Does the `.get()` method return the `default value` both when a `keyError` is raised and if the value returned is 0 or an empty set?

Is it has something to do with the fact that the dict object is immutable and that when I point to the value stored on `key = 1`, I am getting passed a reference to a object that equates to False.

I know I could write my own get method that does a

```
def get(key, default=None):
    try: return x[key]
    except KeyError: return default
```

but I would like to have a more in depth understanding of the `.get` method.

Comment: watch this pycon 2010 video on dictionaries: http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1` != `'1'`; an `int` isn't equal to a `str`.

```
>>> x = {1:0}
>>> 
>>> print x.get('1', 'a')
a
>>> print x.get(1, 'a')
0
```

Comment: Note that dictionaries consider `1` and `1.0` as same keys due to same `hash()` value,  so `x[1]` and `x[1.0]` are equivalent.

Comment: Yep -- even `1+0j` will work, or `decimal.Decimal(1)`, or `fractions.Fraction(1,1)`, etc.  Although that's because they compare equal too, not merely because they have the same hash value (otherwise every collision would be disastrous!)

Comment: Totally agree with that. From `hash.__doc__` : **Two objects with the same value have the same hash value.**

Answer (score 4):

You made mistake in your first experiment:

```
>>> x = {1: 0}
>>> x.get('1', 'a')
'a'
>>> x.get(1, 'a')
0
```

In Python, dict keys can be any hashable type, not just strings.